# BigQuery - Append missing records from one table to another

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables - 'todays_data' and 'full_data' with same schema(Id string, name string, Age string). Records in 'todays_data' may or may not be available in 'full_data'. I need to identify the new records(new Id) in 'todays_data' and append it to 'full_data'(Id is the reference key). How to achieve this using 1)Web-UI SQL statement and 2)bq command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a query you should run with a `full_data` table as a `Destination Table` and with `Append to table` as a `Write Preference`

```
SELECT id, name, age
FROM todays_data
WHERE NOT id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM full_data
  GROUP BY id
)
```

See more for how to achieve this for WebUI and in Commmand line in [Storing results in a permanent table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#storing_synchronous_results_in_a_permanent_table)